# Idiomatic ruby refactor of if statement

Tags: ruby, xpath, refactoring

I have the following code:

```
link = if !activity.xpath('.//a[text()="Delete"]').empty?
         activity.xpath('.//a[text()="Delete"]')
       elsif !activity.xpath('.//a[text()="Delete Photo"]').empty?
         activity.xpath('.//a[text()="Delete Photo"]')
       elsif !activity.xpath('.//a[text()="Unlike"]').empty?
         activity.xpath('.//a[text()="Unlike"]')
       elsif !activity.xpath('.//a[text()="Hide from Timeline"]').empty?
         activity.xpath('.//a[text()="Hide from Timeline"]')
       end

if link
  @agent.get(link.attribute('href').value)
end
```

I have the feeling that it is not idiomatic at all, as there is a lot of duplication. Basically all I want is to find a link with the text 'Delete'. If there is not one, try to find 'Delete Photo', then 'Unlike', then 'Hide from Timeline'. Then, if there was any link found, get the 'href' attribute and request that page.

Is there a way to make this less verbose and more idiomatic ruby code?

Comment: You can always write `!any_collection.empty?` as `any_collection.any?`.

Comment: This kind of question is what http://codereview.stackexchange.com is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably do it this way:

```
link = nil # or ''
['Delete', 'Delete Photo', 'Unlike', 'Hide from Timeline'].detect do |text|
  link = activity.xpath(".//a[text()='#{text}']")
  !link.empty?
end
link = nil if link.empty? # check if link is empty, in case if none of the 
# text is present. or you could probably wrap the above code in a method
# which can be used in other methods.
# Similar Cary Swoveland's answer, his answer is also good.

if link
  @agent.get(link.attribute('href').value)
end
```

Read more about [`detect` here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect).

This gives you the flexibility to define an array anywhere(method/constant) in your code which should be accessible, and pretty easy to update(add/remove new/old text) since I won't have to bother myself with being cautious while adding/removing `if-eslif`.

NOTE: Just make sure that you put your text in an order in which you want to do a lookup for text when defining such array. If you see the array above, it is ordered like you have mentioned in your question.

Comment: Nice! Didn't knew detect before (I am still new to ruby).

Comment: Actually, `present?` comes from Rails, it doesn't exists in Ruby, I forgot about it before posting it and after realizing that your tags don't have rails, I switched it to `!...empty`.

Comment: Is there a way to not return the text (like 'Delete') but the return value of xpath() for given text? Or is it a bad idea and it's better to do it in two steps?

Comment: Good answer. Newbies: `Enumerable#detect` is the same as (one is an alias) `Enumerable#find`. Also note how the single and double quotes have been changed in `xpath`'s argument. That's because `#{text}` must be within the double quotes to be evaluated. Yes, it's also within single quotes, but single quotes are just treated as characters when within double quotes (e.g., `puts "'cat'"` prints the string `'cat'`).

Answer (score 2):

I admit to being unfamiliar with `Xpath`, but I think the following very simple solution should work fine:

```
def find_a_link
  ["Delete", "Delete Photo", "Unlike", "Hide from Timeline"].each do |c|
    link = activity.xpath(".//a[text()='#{c}']")
    return link if link.any?
  end
  nil
end

link = find_a_link
@agent.get(link.value) if link
```

If you want to allow for the possibility that `activity.xpath(".//a[text()='#{c}']")` might return `nil`, change the operative line to:

```
return link if link && link.any?
```

Note that `any?`, `empty?`, `all?` and `find/detect` all stop enumerating elements of the collection as soon as a `true-false` conclusion is obtained.

Comment: The idea was to get link, not just find that it exists.

Comment: @CarySwoveland :  This is also a good answer, It's always a good idea to wrap/isolate such code in a method which can be reused in different places.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby 2.0+:

```
link =
  ['Delete', 'Delete Photo', 'Unlike', 'Hide from Timeline']
    .lazy
    .map { |text| activity.xpath(".//a[text()='#{text}']") }
    .find { |link| !link.empty? }
```

or (no `if link` required, I understand `@agent.get` doesn't return anything useful )

```
  ['Delete', 'Delete Photo', 'Unlike', 'Hide from Timeline']
    .lazy
    .map { |text| activity.xpath(".//a[text()='#{text}']") }
    .drop_while(&:empty?)
    .take(1)
    .each { |link| @agent.get(link.attribute('href').value) }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my misunderstanding of the question. Your answer, which I had not seen before, is rather cool.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Xpath`. Does `activity.xpath(".//a[text()='#{"Delete"}']")` return either an `Xpath` instance or `nil`? If not, what type of object does it return?

Comment: @CarySwoveland No idea, but looking at the original code it returns something that can be either empty or not empty. In the latter case it can be used in `@agent.get`.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it. I'm using Mechanize. This xpath method either returns an empty array or an array of Nokogiri (xml parser) elements.